# In the episode "That Which Survives" where is the location of the pod that enabled Scotty to access the matter - antimatter flow?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, star-trek-tos, engineering

Scotty crawled into a pod were he was going to manually shut off the flow of fuel with a magnetic probe. Scotty installs explosives at the end of the service crawlway that will permit Spock to jettison the pod if Scotty ruptures the magnetic bottle. Where is the location of this crawlway and pod?

Comment: You just turn left at the convenient plot junction and there it is, through the mashers and next to the end of the episode.

Comment: I don't think there is an official placement in the TOS ship.  Most of the diagrams and plans were published years after the series ended.

Comment: @SteveED - There is the cutaway diagram [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XFNda.jpg) which I posted at the bottom of my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108126/22250), which is at least semi-canonical since it appeared (without labels) on a screen in an episode of *Enterprise*. It isn't entirely clear where the pods would be on this diagram but they could be the purple rounded things at the bottom.

Comment: by the same criteria the franz joseph deck plans were shown briefly on a computer screen on he bridge of TMP, both of which were earlier than the linked drawing and Enterprise series.  They show the large engine room at the center back of the saucer just in front of the impulse engines

Answer (score 3):

## Right here:

[image]

([Source](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/federation-starship-uss-enterprise.php))

I can't verify the canonicity of this blueprint, but it's probably as good as you're going to get!

Comment: Although well made, this is not canon, and contradicts both the fasa designs and the franz joseph tech manual and plans (which were not canon either).  I believe this version was published after the first movie so the TOS 1701 matches the TMP 1701

Comment: @SteveED I'm pretty sure these are plans of the original non-refit Enterprise based on the warp nacelles. They may indeed contradict other plans but to the best of my knowledge there are no official or canon plans

Comment: The outline is the TOS design, but the actual artwork was created after the movie came out to retrofit the design of the engines to match TMP